# Trouble returning a valid result while integrating Stripe API into my Meteor app

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

Here's the rundown:

- I'm trying to run Stripe API on my Meteor app asynchronously
- Long story short, everything works (i.e. subscription and charge is/are created normally and shows up in my Stripe dashboard)
- When errors occur, the errors throw normally and show on client via user friendly alerts
- I have a problem when there is a success and customer subscription is created, the result is not present in client and instead always returns as an error, despite it being a successful process

Here's what my method looks like on the server:

```
createCustomer: function(token, email, plan){
  try{
    let createCustomer = Meteor.wrapAsync(stripe.customers.create);
    let result = createCustomer({
      source: token,
      email: email,
      plan: plan
    });

    let subscription = {
      customer: result.id,
      sub: result.subscriptions.data[0].id,
      plan: result.subscriptions.data[0].plan.name
    };

    Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: subscription});

  } catch(error){
  if(error.code === "incorrect_cvc"){
    throw new Meteor.Error("incorrect_cvc", error.message);
  }
// More of such errors follows
  }
}
```

Here's what it looks like on the client:

```
 Stripe.card.createToken({
    number: number,
    cvc: cvc,
    exp_month: exp,
    exp_year: exp_year,
    address_zip: zip,
    address_country: country
  }, function(status, response){
    if(response.error){
      console.log("Make sure all fields are filled before submitting order.");
    } else{
      let token = response.id;
      Meteor.call("createCustomer", token, email, plan, function(error, result){
        if(result){
        console.log("Congratulations, everything worked!");
        } else{
          if(error.error === "incorrect_cvc"){
            console.log("oops, the CSV is incorrect");
          } 

          // More of such errors follow..
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

So, everything works in terms of when there is a real error, it throws fine on server + client. When user uses card, the charges are created and subscription is always created. **HOWEVER**, when there is a success and everything clicking fine, I still receive an error on client via callback and the result is never `true` or triggered. No idea why.

Comment: You could have success with your stripe call then failure in your own code and it would be caught by the same `catch` block. Are you sure that `let subscription = {
      customer: result.id,
      sub: result.subscriptions.data[0].id,
      plan: result.subscriptions.data[0].plan.name
    };` executes without error? Or could `Meteor.userId()` be undefined?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Everything is defined and works perfectly. The subscription is inserted in the user's document and the subscription is created on Stripe. The error still returns on client. Even if I remove the subscription block and just call `stripe.customers.create`, there is still an error.

Comment: When I use promises instead, it works fine with the results. However, I have trouble displaying the errors on the client. Lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% up on Meteor, but it looks to me like your `createCustomer` method doesn't actually return anything, so the `result` from your `(err, result)` might never have anything in it?

As was mentioned in the comments, you might want to separate out the steps and wrap each in its own `try-catch` set so you can better isolate the issue.

Also, I feel like you could probably generalize your server-side error code to something like:

```
throw new Meteor.Error(error.error, error.message);
```

And I might even be tempted to do something like this, at least during testing/development - that way you can actually `console.log()` the original error in the browser:

```
throw new Meteor.Error(error.error, error.message, JSON.stringify(error));
```

Comment: You are actually right. I completely forgot about adding a return method. It works fine now. I worked on this for such a long time that I couldn't see the simple solution.

Comment: Awesome - glad to hear it! :D